# Is there only text between two processing instructions?

Tags: xslt, xpath-2.0

This is my XML file:

```
<root>
    <?pistart ?>
    <elt>
    <?pistop ?>
    </elt>
</root>
```

Now (using XPath 2.0) I'd like to know if there is only text between the processing instruction `pistart` and the next processing instruction `pistop`. The answer above would be 'no, there is an start element tag'.

A `pistart` can never occur after another `pistart` without a corresponding `pistop`. Thus this is not possible (if it helps to solve my problem):

```
<root>
    <?pistart ?>
    <elt>
    <?pistart ?>
    <?pistop ?>
    </elt>
    <?pistop ?>
</root>
```

Comment: I presume there can be multiple pairs of pistart and pistop? In what context are you evaluating this - what would be the expected output?

Comment: Does it have to be pure XPath (2.0) or XSLT (2.0) (where you could use `<xsl:for-each-group select="/root//node()" group-starting-with="processing-instruction('pistart')"><xsl:value-of select="every $group-member in current-group()[position() gt 1 and position() lt last()] satisfies $group-member instance of text()"/></xsl:for-each-group>`, perhaps with one additional check to exclude any nodes before the first pi.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes, there can be multiple instances of these pairs. They are used by OxygenXML for highlighting text.

Comment: @MartinHonnen not necessarily pure XPath/XSLT 2. I will try out your solution and report back, your solution would be fine, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps (assuming the pistart is the context item):

```
exists(following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]
/following-sibling::node()[1][self::processing-instruction(pistop))
```

Comment: Do I understand this right: if exists( the next sibling is of type text of which the next sibling is the processing instruction  ), correct? So `[self::text()] means: this node is of type `text()`?

Comment: The filter expression `X[self::text()]` returns `X` if it is a text node, or an empty sequence otherwise. So the logic of `axis::node()[1][self::text()]` is to select the next node on "axis" provided it is a text node. If you dig a little deeper, `self::text()` returns the context node if it is a text node, or nothing otherwise; because it is used in a predicate, we have a node-set being treated as a boolean, and it's true if the node-set is non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion in my comment, I think

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/root//node()"
        group-starting-with="processing-instruction('pistart')">
        <xsl:if test="self::processing-instruction('pistart')">
            <xsl:variable name="end" select="current-group()[self::processing-instruction('pistop')]"/>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="
                every $group-member in current-group()[position() gt 1 and . &lt;&lt; $end]
                satisfies $group-member instance of text()"
            />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

will do to output `true` for any group of pi pairs satisfying the condition and false for those not satisfying it.

It might be easier to nest an additional `for-each-group group-ending-with="processing-instruction('pistop')"` to grab the nodes to check.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath 1.0 expression**(which, of course, is also an XPath 2.0 one)

Assuming the pistart is the context item:

```
boolean(following::node()[not(self::text())][1][self::processing-instruction('pistop')])
```